# Determine for what values of $x$ the given series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, power-series, proof-explanation

The given series is

> $\sum_{n=1}^∞
> (1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+...+\frac{1}{n}
> )x^{n} $.

I tried it by using Cauchy Root Test as follows-

Let 
$y=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+...+\frac{1}{n} )^{1/n}$,

*then by taking logarithm both sides,we get*

$\log(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+...+\frac{1}{n} )$

Since, $\log(0)=-\infty$. So, $\log(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+...+\frac{1}{n} )=-\infty$.

Applying,L'Hôpital's rule,we get

$\log(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n-2)^2}+...+...+... )}{(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+...+\frac{1}{n} )}$.(**Please Check this step!!**)

Since,$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ & $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\infty$.So,$\log(y)=0\implies y=1$.

Now let $a_n=(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+...+\frac{1}{n} )x^{n} $. Then,$$(a_n)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+...+\frac{1}{n} )^{1/n}x$$

$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\vert (a_n)^{1/n}\vert=1.x$.By ,**Cauchy root test** the given series converges if $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^{1/n}<1$.Hence, the given series converges if $\vert x\vert<1$.

**I  NEED TO KNOW WHETHER MY SOLUTION IS CORRECT OR NOT?**

Comment: It would have been simpler to use the ratio test if you know $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k \sim \log(n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two serious problems. The first one is your assertion that
$$
\log\Bigl(1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n\Bigr)=-\infty.
$$
It is well known (harmonic series) that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n\Bigr)=+\infty,
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\Bigl(1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n\Bigr)=+\infty.
$$
The second one is about the use of L'Hôpital's rule. It is incorrect by two reasons: 1) you have a sequence, not a function and 2) the index of summation is also a variable.

There are several ways to solve the problem. For example, from the inequality
$$
1\le1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n\le n
$$
it follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n\Bigr)^{1/n}=1.
$$
Or you can use the well known fact that
$$
1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n\sim\log n.
$$

Comment: :From where,i can get the proof the last fact?

Comment: :Thanks for the elegant suggestion of the sandwich theorem,i should've given a thought about it......

Answer (score 2):

Since both $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n$ and $-\log(1-x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ have radius of convergence equal to one, the same holds for their (Cauchy) product
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} H_n x^n = -\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}. $$
In particular the LHS is convergent for any $x\in(-1,1)$ and clearly is not convergent for any $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus(-1,1)$ since in such a case the main term is not $o(1)$.